# Passing data to a jQuery event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

### Scenario

In a GUI, a user inserts some text in a text input and then clicks a button: inserted text will be displayed in a div.

I have found a trivial solution ([demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/aNDgC/4/)), that is setting the output text inside the handler accessing the input element object. It sucks.
Rather, I would pass the input text (not the element) to the handler.

### Question

How can I pass parameters (the input message text in this case) to the handler function?

Comment: you need to access to the input element in some way: you have to get the value of the input when you click the button. You may avoid to hardcode the reference to the input but you still need to access it inside the handler

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I modified the code in [your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aNDgC/8/). In jQuery, you can pass data as an argument and access it using `event.data` [jQuery reference](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

Comment: @Fabrizio, I believe he is not asking for that.

Comment: @ADC for that your code is best. or you can pass reference of input fields modiefied jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aNDgC/7/

Comment: @Shusl : "SCENARIO In a GUI a user *inserts* some text..." So I suppose the input is not pre-filled with some value...

Comment: now it works indeed, but in this way the handler function must stil access the input element object. So I'd like to understand from OP if this answer is eligible or not

Comment: I get you now. Instead of passing the $('#txtMessage').val, the element itself is passed to the handler. When the handler access the event data, the actual input value is accessed and displayed.

Comment: The event data is supposed to be a map.  Passing a jQuery object directly could have unintended consequences.

Answer (score 3):

```
/*
 * I would not to referer UI elements here
 * Rather I would pass the $('#txtMessage').val() to the handler
 */
```

That is impossible.

If you want to use the current value of that input element then you *have to access the UI element itself*.

If your intent is to decouple the event handler from knowing which *specific* element is to be  accessed, that's easily done by using event data to pass it to the handler, e.g.:

```
$(sel).on('click', {
   source: document.getElementById('txtMessage')
}, handler);
```

and the in the callback:

```
function handler(event) {
    var txt = event.data.source.value;
    ...
}
```

Note that the jQuery event data is supposed to be a map of `key: value` pairs as shown above.  Passing in a jQuery object directly as shown in the accepted answer could easily break.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, it is my intent to decouple the event handler from the source element. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Check this - http://api.jquery.com/event.data/

Your JS would be something like this (untested):

```
$('#myButton').on("click", {val: $('#txtMessage').val()}, function(event){
    $('#divOutput').html(event.data.val);
});​
```

Comment: No, it is just the same solution suggested by Shusl [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aNDgC/8/).

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the current value of the input element. It basically still accesses the input element but there's no way to avoid that if you wish to acquire the current value

```
$('#myButton').on("click", {val: function (){ return $('#txtMessage').val()}}, function(event){
    $('#divOutput').html(event.data.val());
});​
```